# how to pass a response object to requests in python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import json
import requests

url = 'smeurl/execute'
payload ={"sme":"yes"}


headers = {'Accept': 'application/json','content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
responseObj =r.json()
print responseObj 



url="myurl/get?key="+str(responseObj )+""
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
  print r.json()
```

I want to pass responseObj to requests.get() in python but when its run its showing as

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

inspite of

responseObj prints what is expected(ie key)

also this url when run in RESTClient with this key 
its giving json datawhich is what to be brought to python code.

Any suggestions pls?

Comment: Here is a hint: Read the full error stack trace, find which line is wrong and compare the error with the line.

Comment: r.json() causes error

Comment: Try using `json.loads(r)`

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer when using json.loads(r)

Comment: Change the last line to `print r.content` and see if that works.

Comment: I doubt the key looks like `{some_json..}`